# right-align div form elements

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div in which I have a text input and a text area like so:

```
<div>
    <input type="test" name="username" /><br />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="70">Enter text here...</textarea>
</div>
```

How do I align the input field and my textarea to the right of my div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="right-align">
    <input type="test" name="username" /><br />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="70">Enter text here...</textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.right-align {
    text-align: right;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/G5rFQ/)

Comment: @user765368 Note that this will align all elements inside the div. This will work such a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Use `float: right;` on all the elements you want to float. Make sure you add clear fix.
This way you can float everything to the right, including images, divs, and anything else.

http://jsfiddle.net/dgvBe/

Answer (score 1):

html :

```
<div>
    <input type="test" name="username" /><br />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="70">Enter text here...</textarea>
</div>
```

css:

```
input , textarea{
   float:right;
   direction:rtl; #for right to left languages
}
```